# Set compiz keybindings to "low priority"

Tags: 10.04, compiz, shortcut-keys

So heres an interesting problem. I am using rubymine, but this applies to any editor. There are key bindings in the editor which make perfect sense and are useful. HOWEVER compiz in it's infinite wisdom decides that IT wants to take the key bindings if it sees them. Example is Alt + Ctrl + Left/Right as prev/next location. Compiz instead wants to switch workspaces.

How do I tell compiz to not execute commands on keybindings if another program handles them? Sort of a "low priority"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compiz doesn't know which keybindings are handled by other programs so you can't set Compiz to some kind of low priority.

I've changed all Compiz keybindings to use the Super key as this key usually isn't used by normal programs.

Comment: not the answer I was hoping for. If nobody else will suggest I will just do this approach.